# Selecting a link/button in a WebView MAUI app for IOS fails and unexpectedly shuts down app

Tags: maui, maui-ios

My application is a simple WebView of a website. It works fine on Android but in the IOS application any link/button causes the application to close unexpectedly.

Similar git issues are found here.

[#17923](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17923)

[#11544](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11544)

(Please note that I am a student, and MAUI tech stack is very new to me so I would appreciate any help and sorry if I am asking about something easily fixed.)

2024-03-08 11:05:01.774516+0000 TestMaui2[8858:146865] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: TestMaui2[8858]/0#-1 LF=0 Thread started: .NET Timer #5 2024-03-08 11:05:02.898907+0000 TestMaui2[8858:146865] [ResourceLoadStatistics] Failed to request allowed query parameters from WebPrivacy. Thread started:  #6 Thread started: .NET TP Gate #7 Thread started:  #8 Loaded assembly: /Users/10ticks/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3209D81A-412F-4859-A55D-3CB8D97B8842/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6DC503C-0B9E-49BD-85C7-9DEF7B671798/TestMaui2.app/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll [External] Thread started:  #9 Thread started:  #10 Thread started:  #11 TestMaui2(8858,0x204da5240) malloc: ** error for object 0x30d14b680: pointer being freed was not allocated TestMaui2(8858,0x204da5240) malloc: ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug ================================================================= Native Crash Reporting ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.

Steps to Reproduce

- Create a MAUI app with WebView of website.
- Start the app on iOS device.
- Try to select any link/button
- Crash

Comment: The issues you linked to contain several suggested workarounds

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement any of these workarounds.

Comment: A complete sample of workaround #1 is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11544#issuecomment-1429831732)

Comment: I have seen this but still been unable to produce a positive result. I don't know how to exactly implement this.

Comment: I tested the [code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21157#issuecomment-1992077055) you provided, and it [works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUSmN.png) on iOS Simulator: iPhone 15 iOS 17.2 My version of VS is 17.9.2, .NET 8

Comment: Just figured out the same! Something wrong with iOS 17.4 simulator. Not sure if this continues with real devices running iOS 17.4. (All works on 17.2).

Comment: Seeing your reply, I immediately tested iOS 17.4, but it [worked well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2BHF.png) on my side... hmm :|

Comment: Are you using Windows? Maybe that affects things? I tried with multiple projects all mine crashed :/

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows VS. Run the app on Mac via Pair to Mac.

Comment: `using Windows VS. Run the app on Mac via Pair to Mac.` Try this?